# Why I can't use "instanceof" for comparison array of Int and Integer?

Tags: java, arrays

Why this code throws a compilation error?

```
Integer[] arr  = new Integer[3];
if (arr instanceof Integer) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

**arr** is an Object and at the same time **Integer** is an Object.  Why I can't compare them with `instanceof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JLS 15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator `instanceof`
>
> > **If a cast (§15.16) of the *RelationalExpression* to the *ReferenceType* would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error.**

Where the use of `instanceof` is

```
if (RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType)
```

Since the casts between `Integer` and `Integer[]` fails because neither is a subtype of the other (their common supertype is `Object`), `instanceof` gives a complication error

> Incompatible conditional operand types Integer[] and Integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly that I wanted to know!

Answer (score 3):

`Integer[]` is not the same as `Integer`. They are two quite different classes: you can see this by checking `Integer[].class == Integer.class`, which will yield `false`.

This shouldn't be surprising: one is an array type, the other isn't. You can invoke `Integer.intValue()` on an `Integer`, and `Integer[].length` on an `Integer[]`, but not `Integer.length` or `Integer[].intValue()`.

Moreover, the only common supertype of the two classes is `Object`, so there is no way that an `Integer` reference can store a `Integer[]`, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I knew, that Integer[] is not the same as Integer. But I was misunderstanding how "instanceof" works. Now it's clear for me!!!